# Вопрос про php и вывод символов

Tags: php

Суть проблемы такова, имеется GET параметр `$_GET['test']` `site.ru/?test=%2BUZq0eFoPqF%2BwhwKppafSN8lU1Ma5WBdvW8WoG8Czyg` При выводе значения test, символы `%2B` заменяются на +, как сделать так, чтобы эти символы не менялись при выводе

Comment: это base64? и зачем вам именно в таком виде + нужен кодом в смысле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка отображается в таком виде в котором ты видишь в браузере, но при входе PHP она уже приведена в нормальный вид. Попробуй это [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) - здесь подробно объясняется.